# Photo not loading using asset() in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, storage

I have written the code for storing and displaying an image

show.blade.php

```
     <form method="POST" action="{{ url('/user/'.$profile->user_id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

<input type="file" name="avatar" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form>
  <img src="{{ asset($profile->avatar_path) }}" width="20px" height="20px">
```

ProfileController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, Profile $profile)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'avatar' => 'nullable|image',
        ]);

        $profile->fill([
                'avatar_path' => request()->file('avatar')->store('avatars', 'public'),
            ]);

        $profile->save();

        // auth()->user()->profile()->update([
        //     'avatar_path' => request()->file('avatar')->store('avatars', 'public')
        // ]);
    }
```

It stores the path as `avatars/XCK6azMSv87qA23YYXemZlPVoSKLN3sor9aUhfhQ.jpeg`

And when I check the `storage/app/public` the image is actually present in `avatars/` folder

In the console it shows

```
GET http://localhost:8000/avatars/XCK6azMSv87qA23YYXemZlPVoSKLN3sor9aUhfhQ.jpeg 404 (Not Found)
```

I have also executed the `php artisan storage:link` command still image does not load.

Comment: Check user's permissions on public folder

Comment: how to do that ?

Comment: Are u on Linux?

Comment: no. im on windows 10

Comment: Did you also do the link for storage and public? If so you probably just need to add /storage in front of the path name. so www.url.com/storage/avatars/stuff.jpg

Comment: @NMahurin no that does not work. console shows GET http://localhost:8000/storagehttp://localhost:8000/avatars/XCK6azMSv87qA23YYXemZlPVoSKLN3sor9aUhfhQ.jpeg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Did you do the symbolic linking for the files? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#configuration

Comment: @NMahurin yes i have done that already

Comment: What does $profile->avatar_path look like?

Comment: @NMahurin "http://localhost:8000/avatars/XCK6azMSv87qA23YYXemZlPVoSKLN3sor9aUhfhQ.jpeg"

Comment: Then you need to change avatar_path to return localhost:8000/storage/avatars/etc.jpg Since that is the path to the linked folder.

Comment: but i have used storage:link so that same copy is available in the public/avatars folder otherwise what was the use for linking ?

Answer (score 3):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk):

> By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in  `storage/app/public`. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`

So, run this command to create a symbolic link:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then you'll be able to use the `asset()` helper to display image in `storage/app/public/avatars/john.jpg` with:

```
{{ asset('storage/avatars/john.jpg') }}
```

Comment: i have already done that please check last line of my question

Comment: yes. and i also used php artisan storage:link so now a shortcut is also available in public folder

Comment: @Raj your image should be in the `storage/app/public/avatars/` and you should use it with `asset('storage/avatars/john.jpg')`

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you just use the static path to the assets image folder in the public folder.
Just create a folder named Image in Public folder of your application.

Store only the name of the image in the database and the file in the Image folder.

When you query the user profile,
 store image name to avatar variable and display the image in blade file using

```
<img src="{{ asset(Image/$profile->avatar) }}" width="20px" height="20px">
```

making it simple.

Comment: im following the laracast's forum tutorial series, there i learned that the image name may collide thus it is better to save as hash rather than giving filename

Comment: yeah it is possible that the image having same name would uploaded. For that, you can simply concatenate the image name with some random variable or the time milisecond before saving the name to the database. It will assure you that every image name is unique.